# Unix mailx html mail not working

Tags: unix, sendmail, mailx

Following html mail using mailx command is working from shell terminal, but the same command is not working from shell script.

```
mailx -s "$(echo -e "${sub} TRP OF ${system} \nContent-Type: text/html")" example@gmail.com < TRP.html
```

I guess it is some small escape character error, but not sure what it is.

Can any one help here?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your vars sub / system are only known in your current environment.

When your sript is called mymail, try

```
. mymail
```

(Start with a dot),
or first export your vars.

When these suggestions fail, debug:
use set -x or temporary put an "echo -e" in front of your line.